# Why is my Set variable throwing error when doing a many-many query?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsp, spring-mvc

I am new to spring and hibernate. I have created a spring-mvc app with hibernate integration and when I run the code I get the below error.

My requirement is to pick the relevant `path` from the `advertisement` given the customer `category`.

This involves two tables respectively along with the 3rd table for many-many mapping.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernate3AnnotatedSessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.Set, at table: customercategory, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(advertisements)]
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1568)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:540)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:229)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:706)
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:663)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:629)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:677)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:548)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:489)
org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:957)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:620)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2476)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2465)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Below is my model class Advertisement

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "advertisement")
public class Advertisement {

@Id
@Column(name="id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;

private String path;

private String name;

public int getId(){
    return id;
}

public String getName(){
    return name;
}

public void setName(){
    this.name=name;
}

public String getPath(){
    return path;
}

public void setPath(){
    this.path=path;
}

}
```

below is another model `customercategory`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "customercategory")
public class CustomerCategory {

@Id
@Column(name="id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;

@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

private Set advertisements;

public int getId(){
    return id;
}

public String getName(){
    return name;
}

public void setName(){
    this.name=name;
}

public Set getAdvertisements(){
    return advertisements;
}

public void setAdvertisements(Set advertisements){
    this.advertisements=advertisements;
}

}
```

Below is my DAO class in which im trying to run a query that needs information from a many-many table.

```
public class CustomerCategoryDAOImpl implements CustomerCategoryDAO {

private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

private int catId;

private String adPath;

public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory){
    this.sessionFactory=sessionFactory;
}

@Override
public String getAdPath(String categoryName) {

    sessionFactory = new Configuration()
            .addResource("com/springapp/mvc/CustomerCategory.hbm.xml")
            .buildSessionFactory();

    Session session=this.sessionFactory.openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();

    Query query=session.createQuery("from CustomerCategory where name=:categoryName");
    query.setParameter("name",categoryName);

    for(Iterator it=query.iterate();it.hasNext();){
        CustomerCategory c=(CustomerCategory)it.next();
        catId=c.getId();

        Set advertisements=c.getAdvertisements();

        for(Iterator it2=advertisements.iterator();it2.hasNext();){
            Advertisement ad=(Advertisement)it2.next();
            adPath=ad.getPath();
        }
    }
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();
    return adPath;
}
}
```

below is my controller class that responds to the url request.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/{category}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public class HelloController {
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void printWelcome(@PathVariable("category") String categoryName,
                           @RequestParam("value") String value,HttpServletResponse response) {

    ApplicationContext context = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext
            ("classpath:/../mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml");

    CustomerCategoryDAO cDAO=context.getBean(CustomerCategoryDAO.class);

    String path = cDAO.getAdPath(value);

    try {

        //Get path to ad for the categoryName from the database
            File adFile = new File(path);
            // get your file as InputStream
            InputStream is = FileUtils.openInputStream(adFile);
            // copy it to response's OutputStream
            org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(is, response.getOutputStream());
            response.flushBuffer();

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException("IOError writing file to output stream");
    }
}


}
```

Below is my dispatcher xml.

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.springapp.mvc"/>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
      destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ccas" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="" />
</bean>

<bean id="hibernate3AnnotatedSessionFactory"
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>com.springapp.mvc.CustomerCategory</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="customerCategoryDAO" class="com.springapp.mvc.CustomerCategoryDAOImpl">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernate3AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

and below is my hibernate xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping package="com.springapp.mvc">
<class name="CustomerCategory" table="customercategory">
    <meta attribute="class-description">
        This class contains the customer category detail.
    </meta>
    <id name="id" type="int" column="id">
        <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
    <set name="advertisements" cascade="save-update" table="customercategory_has_advertisement">
        <key column="customerCategory_id"/>
        <many-to-many column="advertisement_id" class="Advertisement"/>
    </set>
    <property name="name" column="name" type="string"/>
</class>

<class name="Advertisement" table="advertisement">
    <meta attribute="class-description">
        This class contains the advertisement records.
    </meta>
    <id name="id" type="int" column="id">
        <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
    <property name="name" column="name" type="string"/>
    <property name="path" column="path" type="string"/>
</class>
```

I have attached an image of my folder structure as well.

[image]

Please help.

Comment: The error says "Could not determine type for: java.util.Set, at table: customercategory for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(advertisements)]" . Check if the advertisements column would fit in a object which is java.util.Set or not.

Comment: Actually there is no single column "Advertisements". Its actually the many-many table. I used a set to map this many-many relationship

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT:**

In order to have a `Many-to-Many` mapping between the two entities you have to specify this mapping in the two sides of the relation, and ***that's what you are missing here*** because you haven't declared a collection of `CustomerCategory` in your `Advertisement` class so you have to add it, your code should like like this:

In the Advertisement class:

```
@ManyToMany(
    cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE},
    mappedBy = "advertisements",
    targetEntity = Advertisement.class
)
private Set<CustomerCategory> customerCategories;
//getters and setters
```

And in your `CustomerCategory` class:

```
@ManyToMany(
    targetEntity=package.CustomerCategory.class,
    cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE}
)
@JoinTable(
    name="CustomerCategoryAdvertisements",
    joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="AdvertisementId"),
    inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="CustomerCategoryId")
)
private Set<Advertisement> advertisements;
```

**Note:**

Specify the `JoinTable` and the `JoinColumn` in the mapping, also use different names for the entities primary keys, so change id to respectively `AdvertisementId` and `CustomerCategoryId`.

---

Your problem is that *you are not defining the type* of the `Set` `advertisments` that's why you got the Exception : `Could not determine type for: java.util.Set`.

So the following declaration:

```
private Set advertisements;
```

Should be:

```
private Set<Advertisement> advertisements;
```

Remember to change the getters and setters as well.

**Note:**

Also I don't see why you are mixing `XML` and `annotations` **Mappings** it can be the cause of this Exception too and surely many other problems, you should use only one of them.

I would recommend you to get rid of the `XML` mapping and use `annotations`, here are some links that you can follow:

- **[Hibernate Annotations jBoss Documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/)**.
- **[Hibernate - Annotations TutorialsPoint tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_annotations.htm)**.
- And the **Many-to-many** section in  **[Mapping entity associations/relationships](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#entity-mapping-association)** in the Documentation.

Comment: how can I solve the xml and annotations issue? in the dispatcher.xml what should I do put if im to use only the XML way? please advice

Comment: Drop the XML and use annotations only - just follow some fresh Spring tutorial / documentation. Btw. you are using Hibernate 3 which is old - Hibernate 4 and Spring 4 are the current versions of those frameworks. If you are learning **be aware of old tutorials**. Things change rapidly.

Comment: Also Im still getting the error even after adding the <Advertisement> thing to my variable declaration, getters and setters

Comment: @mayooran get rid of the XML and use annotations, take a look at the links in my EDIT for further information, and for the problem you should change the getters and setters as well.

Comment: @chsdk I removed the xml and kept the annotations thing. And I added this Set<Advertisements> for getters and setters as well. Also added the annotation @ ManyToMany for getAdvertisements method in CustomerCategory. But im still getting the error. Please help

Comment: @mayooran take a look at my EDIT, you were missing **the most important part of the mapping**.

Comment: @chsdk now that exception is gone. But in CustomerCategoryDAOImpl class, after running the query I get this exception now. org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: com.springapp.mvc.CustomerCategory cannot be cast to com.springapp.mvc.Advertisement
 org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:978)

Any idea? please advice

Comment: @mayooran I think you are trying to cast a `CustomerCategory` object to an `Advertisement` object, that's what the Exception says.